# Why would I ever use a DoublyLinkedList in PHP?

Tags: php, data-structures

I've recently come across some of the PHP-SPL data structures and the I've been looking over the first one, [the doubly linked list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php). I've a rough idea what a linked list is and now I can see what a doubly linked list is but my question is: What in the world would I do with this?

I seems like it would be just as easy to use an array. Can some Computer Science type enlighten me?

Comment: I totally agree with your skepticism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike a singly-linked list, a doubly linked list can walk the list in either direction, and do object insertion and deletion in the middle of the list in O(1) (provided you already has access to spot in the list where it's going to happen, unlike a singly linked list. That said, doubly linked lists are inferior in other ways and are defiantly not something you'll come across that often in practice.

Comment: They have their uses in certain situations and for certain algorithms. They are less important in PHP, where an array is quite dynamic. In other languages where the size of an array is fixed at declaration, then a linked list, doubly-linked or not, might be a better fit for the solution. The cost of resizing an array in these languages can sometimes be much higher than the overhead of a linked list.

Comment: the SPL implementation doens't seem to allow insertion in the middle of the list - although if it did I could see the value.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing an appropriate data structure is not necessarily about what is easy for you, but what uses less memory and is faster for the machine. In the case of a doubly linked list, it would be useful whenever you need to iterate in either direction, insert anywhere in constant speed, but don't need random access.

Now given that in PHP you are usually working with small datasets, you don't have to worry very much about that sort of thing. And if you are working with large datasets, you may be better off writing the code in C. So it's unlikely that you'll ever benefit enough from such structures in PHP to ever need to use them.

But there could be that "in between" area where using one of the Spl data structures does lower the memory usage sufficiently enough to be worthy of use. (I did a simple test, and 1M integers in an array takes 200MB. The double linked list takes 150MB. Time to iterate over them was very comparable.)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the chances of coming across something like this in the wild are unlikely, unless you're working for a company like Google or Facebook, where they're dealing with insane amounts of data and have a **need** to optimize list traversal to allow for node removal and addition. As a rule of thumb, if your application is *that* slow, you're most likely doing something wrong elsewhere (I know that's not your question, but I thought I'd just throw that in ;)).

For small to medium sized sites with small to medium sized data requirements, I'd say that an array would suffice (not to mention more readable and understandable by the average web developer ;)).